How can I add a delete button for for each option
The idea is to add for each option inside the dropdown X button to delete the row.
I tried some , but I'm a very beginner in JavaScript.
        <form id="ReportIDSection1" class="col-lg-6 section1">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group mb-3 col-lg-11">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text lclient">clients info:</span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control col-lg-12 reportidclientname"
                            id="ReportIDClientName" onchange="ShowClients()"></select>
                </div>
            </div>

    function ShowClients() {
        $('#ReportIDClientName').empty();
        var ReportIDClientName = document.getElementById("ReportIDClientName");
    
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = "*** לקוח חדש ***";
        ReportIDClientName.add(option);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < Clients.length; i++) {
            var clientOption = $('#ReportIDClientName').find('option:contains(' + Clients[i].Name + ')');
            if (clientOption.length == 0) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = Clients[i].Name;
                ReportIDClientName.add(option);   
            }
        }
        if (ReportIDClientName.childElementCount > 1)
            ReportIDClientName.selectedIndex = 1;
    }


You cannot add action elements inside a select's <option>. You might need to create a custom select box dropdown for that purpose. Or rather, instead of a select box, use a table  and add the necessary column for the X buttons.

Alternatively, have a single delete button (outside the select) that removes the currently selected option
